# PC usb host communicate with Android accessory mode through libusb

Tags: android, libusb

I want to communicate to Android accessory mode from HOST PC(linux) through libusb and I have already set up android accessory mode.   but I can't get usb handle.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 18d1:2d00 Google Inc. Android-powered device in accessory mode
```

when I use libusb to get this usb handle , it always return NULL. How to fix it ? Thanks.

```
libusb_init(NULL);
struct libusb_device_handle* handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, 0x18d1,0x2d00);
// this handle always return NULL
```

Comment: are you using ndk?

Comment: @Muhammad Hassaan No,  Android side is java and PC side is c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened debug message in libusb by `libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);`
And I found that this user do not have permission to visit this usb device.

I fixed it by adding a file named `51-android.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

51-android.rules :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```